# Need help with putting conditions on a column in a result set

Tags: db2

I am using IBM DB2.

So, I have a SQL query in which I am retrieving a person's SSN from a table.
I want to put conditions on that SSN column of the result set, conditions like :

1) It should start with only 9.

2) There should not be 2 consecutive zeros at 4th and 5th positions. (For eg. it cant be 999006667).

3) Max. length of a SSN can be 9.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the number numeric?  A string of characters? Etc.

Comment: I tried substr(SSN_TX,4,5) != '00' and the query is working but I dont really have any test data to test if its actually running. Do you think this condition would be working?

Comment: SSN is a VARCHAR field

Answer (score 3):

How about something simple like this:

```
SELECT SSN, PersonName 
FROM YourTable
WHERE SSN LIKE '9__00____'
```

The LIKE pattern both controls the required characters and the 9-character length constraint.

But the pattern should also include only numeric values, so then it would be:

```
SELECT SSN, PersonName 
FROM YourTable
WHERE SSN LIKE '9[0-9][0-9]00[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

(Tested on Microsoft SQL Server, alas, but I believe it should be the same on DB2.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply RLF but what would I replace underscores ["_"] with in the above '9__00____'? I am kinda new to writing queries thus this question.

Comment: The `_` means any single character qualifies.  The `[0-9]` means only a numeric character qualifies. (I understood that you were trying to limit which strings can be selected.)

Comment: Are you trying to convert existing SSNs into a 9__00____ value or are you trying to select only SSNs with that pattern?

Comment: I just got a Regex to apply on that SSN column. I dont know anything about Regex. Can you suggest some website to learn basics on Regex?

Comment: The string I showed above is a Regular Expression pattern that is support by many versions of SQL.  Since you "got a RegEx" you will need to know the rules of the particular RegEx you chose.

Comment: I got this Regex 
([1-57-8][0-9]{2}|0([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])|6([0-57-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-57-9]))([1-9][0-9]|[0-9][1-9])([1-9]\d{3}|\d[1-9]\d{2}|\d{2}[1-9]\d|\d{3}[1-9]) 
what is this? I dont have any idea what this is.

Comment: @user3845894 When you change the topic as you have, you should start a new question.

Comment: Alright thanks RLF. I have started a new question chain.